# reusing modal fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using the twitter bootstrap modal plugin. The submit from the modal submits data to the server.

For some reason, when I open and submit the modal multiple times the submit is firing as many times as the modal has been opened previously.

So if I click "update" on a row. Edit and save, it fires once since that's the first attempt.
If I then click "update" on a second row. Edit, and save, it fire's twice.
3rd time fires 3 times, 4 fires 4. So on, so forth.

I've been trying to resolve this for days now and have found nothing. Some guidance would be leave me eternally grateful.

Comment: You are very likely binding the events on click when they should be binded on load, please post your code so it can be corrected.

Comment: A little bit of sample code would help to understand what's going on.

Comment: @Duopixel you should add that as an answer because it can't be anything else

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have fixed this issue:

I have a global variable `delete_id=0` just after the `<script>` tag to store the ID which I want to delete (this can be dynamic to use server side script). I have also added ID `myModalAction` for the `Delete` button in my modal HTML.

I have called the modal this way:

```
$('.delete_row').click(function (){
    delete_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#myModal').modal();
});
```

And for `myModalAction`:

```
$('#myModalAction').click(function(e){
    $('#'+delete_id).remove();
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
});
```

Complete working code can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/siddiquinoor/jdzpuzpy/).

Answer (score 0):

You were probably adding the `.on('click'` event on the dynamically generated page inside the modal, so each time the modal was loaded it was adding another event listener to the DOM, therefore generating multiple actions when the button was clicked.

The answer is to add `.off` before the .on('click' event, in order to unbind previous event listeners.

```
$('.delete_row').off().on('click',function (){
    //your code here
});
```