# angularstrap typeahead in modal triggers each change multiple times

Tags: angularjs, typeahead, angular-strap

I've got an angularStrap typeahead in an angularStrap modal, the typeahead control works correctly excepted that the change event is repeated as much time as the modal has been opened/closed since its creation.

It seems like if a listener was added to the typeahead every time the modal is shown but I cannot find a way to fix this issue. Maybe not a bug but a misuse on my side.

For instance, if the modal has been open then closed 3 times, the 4th opening and typing in the typehead will triggers 4 calls to the *getParentItem* handler (see here below) for each typed character...

I cannot post image yet since this is my first question but the chrome console gives something like this (where the number is the number of identical logs in a row visually presented in a blue circle) :

- getParentItem => undefined
- getParentItem => i
- getParentItem => it
- getParentItem => ite
- 2 getParentItem => undefined
- 2 getParentItem => i
- 2 getParentItem => it
- 2 getParentItem => ite
- 3 getParentItem => undefined
- 3 getParentItem => i
- 3 getParentItem => it
- 3 getParentItem => ite
- 4 getParentItem => undefined
- 4 getParentItem => i
- 4 getParentItem => it
- 4 getParentItem => ite

Env :

- AngularJS v1.3.0-build.3029+sha.7df7d1a
- AngularStrap @version v2.0.5 - 2014-08-07

The code is as following :
**In the *module.js***
I've changed the modal handling that way to be sure not to recreate a modal every time and have several instance. The problem is the same either ways.

```
...
/**
 * Edit item creating modal if required
 */
$scope.editItem = function(event) {
  if ('undefined' === typeof this.modalEdit) {
    this.modalEdit = $modal({
      scope: this,
      animation: 'am-fade-and-scale',
      title: 'Insert/Edit Item',
      template: 'partials/item.html',
      show: false
    });
  }
  this.showModalEdit();
};
/*
 * Show edition modal
 */
$scope.showModalEdit = function() {
  this.modalEdit.$promise.then(this.modalEdit.show);
};
/*
 * Hide edition modal
 */
$scope.hideModalEdit = function() {
  if ('undefined' !== typeof $scope.modalEdit) {
    $scope.modalEdit.hide();
  }
};
 /*
 * Propose parent items according val
 */
$scope.getParentItem = function(val) {
  console.info('getParentItem => ' + val);
  if ('undefined' !== typeof val && 2 < val.length) {
    $http.get('/api/items/' + val, {})
      .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('success');
      })
      .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('error');
      });
  }
};
...
```

**And in the modal template *item.html***

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <form method="post" ng-submit="upsert()" ng-controller="ItemCtrl">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h3 class="modal-title" ng-bind="title"></h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
          <div class="form-group">
            <h5>Parent Item</h5>
            <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" ng-model="item.parent" name="parent" data-animation="am-flip-x" data-limit="25" ng-options="item.uid as item.label for parent in getParentItem($viewValue)" placeholder="Select a parent item" bs-typeahead required autofocus>
          </div>
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" ng-click="$hide()">Cancel</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Validate</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any idea will be welcome since I've already spent many hours on this issue refactoring my code several times and found nothing regarding it anywhere except this [reusing modal fires multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165890/reusing-modal-fires-multiple-times) but with no follow-up...

Answer (score 0):

After several tests and hours on my console, I found that creating a new scope for the modal did solve the problem. Probably due to scope management in angular and also inheritance behavior I've not fully understood yet.

Explanation (observed but not fully understood)

Using the controller scope itself for the modal as I did before ("scope: this" or "scope: $scope") resulted in identical $$watchers for the scope were stacked everytime I opened the modal (watchers of the modal properties), the previous ones never being released/destroyed, ending in dozens/hundreds $$watchers after some opening/closing of the modal working an triggering same events.

Note:

- during this journey in angular scopes, I also discover than when calling a function of the main scope (getParentItem for instance) from the modal scope, "$scope" was refering to the main scope while "this" was refering to the local scope itself (ie the modal or control sub-scope), this seems logical after all. I didn't fully understood the scopes creation  process in directives ... though trying hard reading for instance : https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes or http://thenittygritty.co/angularjs-pitfalls-using-scopes, but that will do it for me and for now.
- I don't bother anymore taking care of creating and using only one modal, the new scope being provided trough the modal method itself though I'm not sure it's safe regarding memory usage.
- modalEdit has become a var also and not a scope property anymore.
- I didn't (and still don't) made a specific controller for the modal (bind in a ng-controller for instance) because I had other interactions with module/controllers/services, in the upsert process mainly that I couldn't resolve easily, probably because of my lack of knowledge since it's my first project using angular.

The working code for me is :

```
$scope.editItem = function(item) {
  var editionScope = $scope.$new(true);
  editionScope.getParentItem = $scope.getParentItem;
  editionScope.upsertItem = $scope.upsertItem;
  editionScope.modes = $scope.modes;
  editionScope.item = item;
  modalEdit = $modal({
    scope: editionScope,
    animation: 'am-fade-and-scale',
    title: 'Item Edition',
    template: 'partials/item.html',
    show: true
  });
};
```